# how do I import iis log files to piwik?

Tags: iis, matomo

when trying to import the log files there isn't really much help from the read-me file or in the tutorial. all the information that you get can be seen bellow. can anyone elaborate on this, for example what do i run it in? any help will be greatly appreciated as I have not got a clue about what i'm supposed to do with this.

```
The most simple way to import your logs is to run:

./import_logs.py --url=piwik.example.com /path/to/access.log
```